# What is the Correct Order Of Execution of a Java Code

Tags: java, jvm

We got this question in our test regarding java code execution :-

Select the correct order of java code execution

a) Class Loader

b) Interpretation

c) Compilation

d) Byte Code Verification

e) Java Source Code

f) Execution

Options :-

1. e-a-c-b-d-f
2. e-a-b-c-d-f
3. e-b-a-c-b-f
4. e-c-a-d-b-f

I marked option 4 as my choice. I don't know the exact reason, but that one sounded best to me.

In result, it said my answer was wrong. T_T

Can someone tell what is the correct answer and why.

(Alleged Right answer by University is option 3)
(And after giving link to this post, the university corrected the solution to option 4)

(After reading comments and solutions by everyone, one gets more insight on execution process, rather than just solving a stupid faulty MCQ...... GREAT COMMUNITY).

Comment: You might question the validity of the test, then. Both Class Loader (runtime) and Interpretation (action JVM does on compilated files) happen after compilation. whatever chain of thought that any of them occur before compilation is wrong. Then again, Class Loader (runtime) is after Interpretation, so, indeed, 4 doesn't seem right to me neither.

Comment: Correct answer is **4**, since you start with Source Code (E), then compile (C) that to bytecode. Since A (Class Loader) and B (Interpretation) both works on bytecode, you can't have A or B before C, so it cannot be the other options. Anyone who thinks otherwise might be confusing Compilation with JIT.

Comment: I'd love to hear the [alleged] "right" answer so that we all could ridicule it mercilessly (;->)

Comment: @Stultuske 4 is correct. Source code -> Compile to bytecode -> Load into memory (class loader) -> Verify the loaded code -> at this point it becomes murky, because interpreting the code is one way of executing it, so B and F are really the same thing.

Comment: To be Honest, I too agree with @Stultuske .

Comment: @HentaiOusama How can you agree that Class Loading is after Interpretation? You can't interpret code until you can see it, and the class loader is what makes the bytecode available to the JVM, so interpretation simply cannot come before class loading.

Comment: Answers were just released (Without explanation obviously)... and the [Alleged] "Right" answer is Option 3.  I think that is totally wrong. Does anyone think that is correct ?

Comment: Option 3 cannot be correct, since it has B twice, and never does D.

Comment: @rkosegi Preparing a class for execution is a [3-step process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-12.html): ***Load***, *Link*, and *Initialize*. The *Link* step has 3 sub-steps: ***Verify***, *Prepare*, and *Resolve*. --- So, no. Verification is a dedicated step that follows the loading step, it is not an integral part of classloading.

Comment: Really? The right answer says that “Interpretation” happens twice and “Byte Code Verification” never happens at all? Or did you make mistakes when copying the answers?

Comment: Lol, these are the actual option @Holger . Anyways, I just mailed the link to  this question to our university. XD. And they changed the solution to option 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct order is *e-c-a-d-b-f*, so correct answer is **4**.

The other three answers are provably wrong, because all three have *a)* before *c)*, but you simply cannot have *a) Class Loader* before the *c) Compilation* step that generates the byte code that the Class Loader is supposed to be loading.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────┐
│ e) Java Source Code (.java file) │     Obvious starting point
└──────────────────────────────────┘
                 ↓
 ┌────────────────────────────────┐
 │ c) Compilation (javac command) │
 └────────────────────────────────┘      Then we compile the source code
                 ↓                       to byte code.
     ┌────────────────────────┐
     │ Bytecode (.class file) │
     └────────────────────────┘
                 ↓
       ┌─────────────────┐               The classloader is responsible for
┌──────┤ a) Class Loader ├─ JVM ┐        locating the byte code and making it
│      └─────────────────┘      │        available to the JVM as a byte array
│                ↓              │
│ ┌───────────────────────────┐ │        In the linking phase of preparing a
│ │ d) Byte Code Verification │ │        class for use, the byte code is
│ └───────────────────────────┘ │        verified by the JVM.
│                ↓              │
│     ┌───────────────────┐     │
│     │ b) Interpretation │     │        This one is a bit iffy, but you can
│     └───────────────────┘     │        argue that the byte code is interpreted
│                ↓              │        before it is executed, but the JVM
│        ┌──────────────┐       │        could easily JIT-compile to native
│        │ f) Execution │       │        code without ever executing the code
│        └──────────────┘       │        in interpretation mode.
└───────────────────────────────┘
```

Note that the `ClassLoader` is also used again later to load *resources* on demand.

Comment: There are some fundamental flaws in the question itself. It start with mixing up *artifacts* (source code, class loader) and *procedures*  (compilation, interpretation, execution), even when trying to apply the most generous interpretation, “execution” is a broad term that actually encloses the other procedures and “compilation” could refer to `javac` but also to the JIT compiler. To add fuel to the flames, `javac` itself is also written in Java and subject to the same steps.